How do you enable the debugger in IntelliJ idea?
I use IntelliJ IDEA to program in Java, but I'm having trouble debugging my code because I can't seem to use the debugging tools like step in, step out, and step over. I cannot access them from my main Java file; Whenever i run my main java file, it opens a new file called FileInputStream.java and I can only access the debugger there.
Why does this happen and How can I fix this?


show your main file and what break points you have placed

Maybe you simply forgot to set a breakpoint in your Main class? Without that the debugger won't stop, but just execute until execution is forced to stop.

RTFM: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html

Set a breakpoint where you want to debug and make sure "Mute breakpoints" button is not enable as it'll just mute breakpoints.
